# Forward fill missing values by group after condition is met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. My dataframe looks like this:

```
id    amount    dummy
1      130        0
1      120        0
1      110        1
1      nan       nan 
1      nan       nan   
2      nan        0
2      50         0
2      20         1
2      nan       nan 
2      nan       nan
```

So, what I need to do is, after the dummy gets value = 1, I need to fill the amount variable with zeroes for each `id`, like this:

```
id    amount    dummy
1      130        0
1      120        0
1      110        1
1       0        nan 
1       0        nan   
2      nan        0
2      50         0
2      20         1
2       0        nan 
2       0        nan
```

I'm guessing I'll need some combination of `groupby('id')`, `fillna(method='ffill')`, maybe a `.loc` or a `shift()` , but everything I tried has had some problem or is very slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why this row `2      nan        0` ?

Comment: Because sometimes that happens and is one of my problems: the first rows of a given `id` might have `nan` values in `amount`, which limits my options

Comment: Yes but why is not `2 0 0` shouldn't you fill with 0 also?

Comment: It might or might not be zero. It depends on the situation (`amount` is how much someone owes one year after the observation, and if `id` didn't finish paying it won't be zero).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I will use

```
s = df.groupby('id')['dummy'].ffill().eq(1)
df.loc[s&df.dummy.isna(),'amount']=0
```

Comment: Beatiful way of combining them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much easier:

```
data[data['dummy'].isna()]['amount'] = 0
```

This will select all the rows where dummy is nan and fill the amount column with 0.

Comment: It is correct, presuming `NaN` will follow after 1.

Comment: Right, I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `ffill()` and mask the still-nan:

```
s = df.groupby('id')['amount'].ffill().notnull()
df.loc[df['amount'].isna() & s, 'amount'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   id  amount  dummy
0   1   130.0    0.0
1   1   120.0    0.0
2   1   110.0    1.0
3   1     0.0    NaN
4   1     0.0    NaN
5   2     NaN    0.0
6   2    50.0    0.0
7   2    20.0    1.0
8   2     0.0    NaN
9   2     0.0    NaN
```

Comment: How is the `dummy` column being used here?

Comment: The way I see it, `dummy` is an attempt to solve OP's problem. Therefore `IIUC` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
df.loc[df['dummy'].isnull(),'amount']=0
df
```

Output will be as follows.

```
    id  amount  dummy
0   1   130.0   0.0
1   1   120.0   0.0
2   1   110.0   1.0
3   1   0.0     NaN
4   1   0.0     NaN
5   2   NaN     0.0
6   2   50.0    0.0
7   2   20.0    1.0
8   2   0.0     NaN
9   2   0.0     NaN
```

Comment: @WeNYoBen, I am still learning pandas, could you please check this once, if this one will work too sir, will be grateful to you. Anyways you are my Lord Krishna who is guiding me in Pandas(seeing your profile, trying to learn :) )

Comment: it will work when null always follow by 1, in op’s case it will work